# queuable apex with more than 100 callouts

Tags: callout, queueable-apex

I am inserting more than 100 lead records via Data Import Wizard.

I have the following trigger:

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
    if(Trigger.new != null){
          system.enqueueJob(new YMTemplateCallout(Trigger.new));
    }
}
```

In the following queueable class I am selecting one of the two templates and performing a callout for each of the lead records passed in from the trigger. I am trying to ensure that it will work for 100s of callouts without hitting the max 100 callout governor limit with this queueable apex. What am I missing here?

```
public class YMTemplateCallout implements Queueable {
    private List<Lead> leadListToCallout;
    YM_Msg_Template_Notify__c data1 = YM_Msg_Template_Notify__c.getvalues('templatecallout1'); //---Whatsapp_Opt_in__c == false
    YM_Msg_Template_Notify__c data2 = YM_Msg_Template_Notify__c.getvalues('templatecallout2'); //---Whatsapp_Opt_in__c == true
    msgtemplateWrapper template = new msgtemplateWrapper();
    msgtemplateWrapper.body TempBody = new msgtemplateWrapper.body();
    msgtemplateWrapper.language lang = new msgtemplateWrapper.language();
    msgtemplateWrapper.template temp = new msgtemplateWrapper.template();
    
    // Constructor
    public YMTemplateCallout(List<Lead> leadsFromTrigger){
        this.leadListToCallout = leadsFromTrigger;  
        YM_Msg_Template_Notify__c data1 = YM_Msg_Template_Notify__c.getvalues('templatecallout1'); //---Whatsapp_Opt_in__c == false
        YM_Msg_Template_Notify__c data2 = YM_Msg_Template_Notify__c.getvalues('templatecallout2'); //---Whatsapp_Opt_in__c == true
        msgtemplateWrapper template = new msgtemplateWrapper();
        msgtemplateWrapper.body TempBody = new msgtemplateWrapper.body();
        msgtemplateWrapper.language lang = new msgtemplateWrapper.language();
        msgtemplateWrapper.template temp = new msgtemplateWrapper.template();
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        for (Lead ld : leadListToCallout) {
          // perform callout
          try{
            //----- Whatsapp_Opt_in__c == false, then send 'templatecallout1' data to hit the API-
            if(!ld.Whatsapp_Opt_in__c){
                lang.code = data1.code__c;
                lang.policy = data1.policy__c;
                temp.language = lang;
                temp.name = data1.name__c;
                temp.namespace = data1.namespace__c;
                tempbody.to = ld.MobileYM__c;
                tempbody.ttl = data1.ttl__c;
                tempbody.type = data1.type__c;
                tempbody.template = temp;
                template.body = tempbody;
                string Jsonbody = JSON.serialize(template);
                Httprequest request = new HttpRequest();
                Http http = new Http();
                request.setMethod('POST');
                string jsonString = data1.url__c + '?bot='+data1.bot__c;
                request.setEndpoint(jsonString);
                request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                request.setHeader('x-auth-token', data1.x_auth_token__c);
                request.setBody(Jsonbody);
                HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            }
            //----- Whatsapp_Opt_in__c == true, then send 'templatecallout2' data to hit the API-
            else{
                lang.code = data2.code__c;
                lang.policy = data2.policy__c;
                temp.language = lang;
                temp.name = data2.name__c;
                temp.namespace = data2.namespace__c;
                tempbody.to = ld.MobileYM__c;
                tempbody.ttl = data2.ttl__c;
                tempbody.type = data2.type__c;
                tempbody.template = temp;
                template.body = tempbody;
                string Jsonbody = JSON.serialize(template);
                Httprequest request = new HttpRequest();
                Http http = new Http();
                request.setMethod('POST');
                string jsonString = data2.url__c + '?bot='+data2.bot__c;
                request.setEndpoint(jsonString);
                request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                request.setHeader('x-auth-token', data2.x_auth_token__c);
                request.setBody(Jsonbody);
                HttpResponse response = http.send(request);  
            }
          }catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('Error::'+e.getMessage());
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see nothing in the code that checks how many callouts remain in the current transaction and that then chains the queueable to process the remaining leads. Limit checking is supported via the [Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) Apex API. Exceptions thrown due to limits are uncatchable.

Comment: Right, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before performing a callout the code needs to check if there are any more callouts permitted in the current transaction. This is done by getting the difference between `Limits.getCallouts()` and `Limits.getLimitCallouts()`. When this is non-zero, you can do a callout. When zero, you cannot.

If you cannot do the callout in the current transaction, it is necessary to stop processing in this queueable invocation and leave the remainder to be processed in a follow-on invocation which can be initiated using `system.enqueueJob(this)`. However, before calling the latter it is important to:

1. Stop iterating any more leads in the current queueable and
2. Remove the leads that have already been processed from the queueable state.

Something like the following should do it:

```
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    Integer sentCount = 0;
    Boolean hitLimit = false;

    // Process as many leads as possible in this transaction, based on limits
    for (Lead ld : leadListToCallout) {
        if (Limits.getCallouts() == Limits.getLimitCallouts()) {
            hitLimit = true;

            // Messy code flow, but this quickly exits the loop
            break;
        }

        // Do your callout
        ...

        // Track how many leads have been processed
        sentCount++;
    }

    if (hitLimit) {
        // Need to chain this queueable to finish processing. First clean up
        // the list of leads needing a callout, removing all those that have
        // been sent already
        for (Integer index = 0; index < sentCount; index++) {
            leadListToCallout.remove(0);
        }

        // Now ensure the remainder get processed by simply re-enqueuing this
        // queueable with its adjusted state
        System.enqueueJob(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this will work for me! Will update.

Comment: Phil, It worked like a charm! Tried with 110 records and all got inserted and all callouts where also where made. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this code is creating a recursive job... when I check the apex job I see more and more jobs are being created endlessly... none of the abort techniques worked. Has raised a case with Salesforce. Can't edit the code either, it says a job is in progress...

Comment: You can edit the code by going to Setup UI, Deployment Settings and tick the "allow" box.

Comment: This code "chains" a job, but this will only go wrong if somehow you hit limits without actually processing any lead records in the queueable at all (and the sentCount is therefore 0 when entering the `if (hitLimit)` block). If you have modified the code in some way, not shown in my outline, and have now got this strange behaviour, please post a new question.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Phil! :-) 

It helped me put together the following: 

`public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    for (Account oldAcc : accNewValues.keySet()) {
        if (Limits.getCallouts() >= Limits.getLimitCallouts()-4) {
            break;
        }

        // perform callouts to update remote account

        accNewValues.remove(oldAcc);
    }

    if (!accNewValues.isEmpty()) {
        System.enqueueJob(this);
    }
}`

Comment: Glad it helped you @RobAlexander. Feel free to upvote if you haven't already ;)

Answer (score 1):

As triggers run in batches of **200**, even if you insert more than 200 records at once.
Technically you can still do **200** callouts from one Queueable class.
Fire 100 calls from `execute` of **Queueable** and fire another 100 calls from `execute` of **Finalizer**.

```
public class QueueableCallout implements Queueable, Finalizer, Database.AllowsCallouts{

    List<String> firstBatchCallouts;
    List<String> secondBatchCallouts;
    
    //Here send two list of 100 each.
    public QueueableCallout(List<String> firstBatchCallouts, List<String> secondBatchCallouts){
        this.firstBatchCallouts = firstBatchCallouts;
        this.secondBatchCallouts = secondBatchCallouts;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext param1) {
        System.attachFinalizer(new QueueableCallout(firstBatchCallouts,  secondBatchCallouts));
        // Iterate frrom 1st batch and do callouts
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
            req.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            System.debug('QueueableContext-> ' + res.getStatus());
        }
    }

    public void execute(FinalizerContext param1) {
        // Iterate frrom 2nd batch and do callouts
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
            req.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            System.debug('FinalizerContext-> ' + res.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

As we know trigger always runs in batch of 200, so you should not have any issues making a callout after separating  `Trigger.new` to two batches of 100 each.

Comment: Trigger.new may contain 1 to 1000s of lead records as these records are inserted using Import Wizard.

Comment: At any point of time, trigger always runs in batches of 200, you may insert 100, 1000 or 100000, it doesn't matter. Every 200 batch gets fresh set of governor limits.

Comment: Finalizers aren't really meant to be used for this purpose. System.enqueueJob can be called to chain Queueable, so you can still use a finalizer to handle any errors, if necessary.

Comment: Yes @sfdcfox. Its not meant for doing callouts.

Comment: N.B. Platform Event triggers can process up to 2000 recs in a trigger context (although this is configurable)